# How to detect whether application is running on Azure VM from inside a Windows Container

Tags: azure, windows-server-2016, containers

For this question, here is the situation:

- Application written in ASP.NET (.NET Framework) is running inside a Windows Container on Windows Server 2016
- The application needs to be able to detect at run time whether it is running inside an Azure VM or not

I have a PowerShell script which can detect whether the app is running inside an Azure VM but this only works when running outside a container.  Once inside a container, this script returns False, which is incorrect.

Does anyone know how to detect whether an application is running inside Azure VM inside a Windows Container?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Most Windows container systems will have a service named Container Execution Service (cexecsvc) present. I've provided you a PowerShell snippet to check if this is present: `If (Get-Service -Name cexecsvc) { return $TRUE }`.